# why do " not authorized to perform this operation" exception come?

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

i am trying to execute a query in a table but when i hit the table an exception come.
"[LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface][Data Record Manager]You are not authorized to perform this operation"
Why it is appearing?
How can we fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a third party database (not one you developed) and either has database security or an owner name on the table(s).
Some developers don't want users changing important tables like configuration or sensitive information so they setup the database to prevent changes. 
If you log in with a user that has rights to that table or specify the owner name, you won't get the exception. If you don't have that information, you'll have to contact the original developer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the chances ,it will start working after restart of database.